# Authorization on twitter

Tags: .net, linq, twitter

I want to use linqToTwitter library to create my own twitter client. How can i make autorization using login and password? Examples provide information how to make autorization throught OAuth (consumer key, secret key etc) but it is not good in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the related [Twitter Developer page](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_auth_shutdown) Basic Authentification has been disabled at the end of August 2010. The only way to make authenticated calls to Twitter is using OAuth since then. (And yes, I partly agree that it would be great if simple username/password authentification via Basic Auth would be possible.)

Comment: is correct.  It is not possible to use the Twitter API with a user's username and password.  There are lots of Twitter libraries out there that do the heavy lifting of OAuth for you.  For .NET, I recommend Twitterizer (http://twitterizer.net).

Comment: The only Twitter API that still [supports](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_concepts#authentication) basic authentication is the streaming API (not users streams, however.)

Answer (score 0):

possible, it is what you want
http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/

Comment: It describe OAuth authorization but i want authorize users just using login and password